# Map mp3 s in Documents directory and convert to AVPlayerItems

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayeritem

I am using this method to convert an mp3 in my main bundle path to an avplayer item:

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Baroon", ofType: "mp3")
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
```

How can I convert every mp3 that exist in the Documents directory automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use FileManager's `contentsOfDirectory(of: URL)` method to get all files in your documents directory and map the ones that contains the mp3 pathExtension:

```
let documents = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
do {
    let playesItems = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documents, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil).compactMap {
        $0.pathExtension == "mp3" ? $0.asset.playerItem : nil
    }
    for item in playesItems {
        print(item.asset.duration)
    }
} catch { print(error) }
```

---

Don't forget to add those helpers to your project:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

extension URL {
    var asset: AVAsset {
        return AVAsset(url: self)
    }
}
extension AVAsset {
    var playerItem: AVPlayerItem {
        return AVPlayerItem(asset: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Bundle` class has a method `urls(forResourcesWithExtension:subdirectory:)` That will return all the files in the bundle (or in a subdirectory of that bundle) with a given file extension. Use that to search for all files with the extension "mp3" and then iterate through them and create `AVPlayerItem`s out of each one.

Comment: Appreciate for your answer❤️